# can you Close a google appmaker app with code?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

Ok so im trying to customize my google domains google waffle. I want my own google sites to appear there and thought id use google appmaker to make a clickable link for every website.

My question is then, can you create an app that opens a website then closes itself? im having trouble with the closing itself part.

Comment: You mean, like opening a link from the app then closing the app itself? you can try with `window.close()`

Comment: Tried and it did not work

Comment: Search for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=window.close+doesn%27t+work to get some information on possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you pretend but if you want to open a link from the app and then close the app, then you can do the following:

```
var url = "https://google.com";
window.open(url, "_blank");
window.top.close();
```